# Long task in Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long task in Javascript that should be performed before the web page content is displayed. During the execution of this task I would like to show an image whose opacity will grow up to 100% (when the task is done).
How this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function , say it's 10 loops, every loop you need to increase the opacity, like this:

```
var curOpacity = 0; 
function doWork(step) {
    for(var j  = 0; j <100000000; j++) { } //simulate work
    console.log("Completed step: " + step);
    $("#element").css('opacity', step * 0.1);  
    if(step < 10)
        setTimeout(function() { doWork(step + 1); });
}
doWork(0);
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/eyvYE/)

On the final step this would be setting the opacity to `1`, completely faded in.  The steps you just need to divide out, you need to increase opacity by `1/numOfSteps` each step...a `.fadeIn()` won't work here because it'll just execute after your code is done...you need to manually set the opacity using [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) inside the loop.

The `setTimeout()` (without an argument it's instant) lets the UI update before the next step starts.

*Note:* this works cross-browser, just use `opacity` and it'll take care of setting `filter:` in IE for instance.

Comment: This won't work. You aren't giving up the CPU, so the UI won't update until your loop completes.

Comment: @Marcelo - Good point, I was testing in Chrome 6 which lets the UI update...answer's updated in a way that'll work cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

Decompose the task into multiple smaller tasks, each of which updates the progress bar appropriately. Then schedule these sub-tasks to run asynchronously using something like the [jQuery Async extension](http://mess.genezys.net/jquery/jquery.async.php). Without the async component, your tasks will hog the CPU until they are finished, and you won't see any interim status updates.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements [DOMContentLoaded Event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Other_events) might be called too late. Please notice the fact that that event is triggered when the whole DOM tree has been loaded. In some cases a web browser might start display web content before `</html>` is reached. You could just please some JavaScript right after `<body>` element (`document.body` is available there, while others DOM elements are not).

Any method you choose the rest of the code stays practically the same.

So now you have to:

1. Create an image and inject it into DOM tree:

   ```
   var img = document.createElement("img");
   img.setAttribute("src", "/path/to/the/image.png");

   document.body.appendChild(img);
   ```
2. Make that image transparent:

   ```
   img.style.opacity = "0";
   ```
3. Start your task
4. Every time the task is one percent closer to the end increase the value of the image's opacity style:

   ```
   img.style.opacity = Math.min(1, (img.style.opacity * 1) + 0.01); 
   // Of course you can increase by any step, not only 0.01 (1%)
   ```

The problem may be the determination of when the task is one step closer to the end. If that task is for example a loop which repeats 10 times then there is easy way to determine it - every single iteration the task progress jumps 10%. But if your task has more complex structure then I think you'll have to define by your own places where task progress is 10, 20, 25, 50, 100%.

```
 task(0);
 //download something using AJAX
 task(30);
 while (i = 0..10) { ... task(+5) }
 doSomething();
 task(80);
 doSthElse();
 task(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers) in modern browsers and partition the task with `setTimeout()` in old ones.